# not able to create create-react-app folder to a desired location using VSCode terminal or windows PowerShell

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am trying to create a new project using create-react-app using the command given on the docs i.e npx create-react-app my-app but its not creating the 'my-app' folder in the address provided in the VSCode terminal(or even PowerShell Terminal) i.e like in my terminal address is(E:\reactjs) but its installing on Desktop

Comment: This maybe because you haven't opened VS Code in the desired folder. Can you please reconfirm that your terminal (in vs code) is showing the desired path.

Comment: Yes, it was showing the desired path and after running the "npx create-react-app my-app" command its creating the folder on desktop(which i think is the default terminal location)